# stage.removeChild throwing an error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, removechild

I've built a simple snake game that uses a Main class (this is my document class), a Snake class and a Food class. The Main class makes a new object of the Snake class, and another of the Food class. Within both the Snake and Food classes, I'm making sprites like so:

```
var segment:Sprite = new Sprite();
segment.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
segment.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
segment.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFF6699, .50, 3, 3, 2, 2, false, false)];
segment.graphics.endFill();
segment.x = x;
segment.y = y;
this.stage.addChild(segment);
this.segments.push(segment);
```

The snake's body is stored in an array of sprites called `segments`. You can see from that code I'm making a new sprite to extend the length of the snake and pushing it to the segments array. I do something similar for any food items, except within the food class I've defined the food sprite as `public var foodSprite:Sprite;` because I only need one on the stage at a time.

Now, when I call the `gameOver()` method from the Main class (where I have my game loop), I want to call `stage.removeChild()` on each of the snake segments and the food sprite. I tried doing this:

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < this.snake.segments.length; i++)
{
    stage.removeChild(this.snake.segments[i]);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main/gameOver()
```

From what I know this should work, as `this.snake.segments[i]` points to a sprite, the one which I want to remove from the stage.

What could be going wrong here? Thank you.

EDIT: I guess it's also worth noting that `segments` is defined as:

```
public var segments:Array = new Array;
```

Comment: You can use `[]` instead of `new Array()`. `public var segments:Array = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please see comments on this answer for the actual solution.**

Try this:

```
for(var i:Number = 0; i < snake.segments.length; i++)
{
    var seg:Sprite = snake.segments[i] as Sprite;

    if(seg.parent)
        seg.parent.removeChild(seg);
}
```

Comment: @MartinHoe If that's the case, then unless `snake.segments[i]` is `null`, this isn't the problem. Do some checks on each of the properties you have in `gameOver()` like `trace("Segment[i]: " + snake.segments[i]);` and see if you get any `null`s in the output.

Comment: Alright, I think I got closer to the problem. Even when I do `trace(this.snake.segments[0])` I get the same null object reference error. I really don't get it, the snake segments array definitely has items as I push new array elements in with its constructor.

Comment: @MartinHoe What if you try `trace(this.snake)` as well as `trace(this.snake.segments)` - do these both exist in the current context?

Comment: Ah, worked it out. Turns out on the first key press `this.snake` was null, because I create the snake object after the keypress. I just added an if to check if `this.snake` was null and if it isn't, remove it. Works now. :)

Comment: @MartinHoe Hone those debugging skills for game dev :P